# Shimano M355 brake handle parts

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, hydraulic-disc-brake, brake-levers

My son has a Diamondback Recoil Comp MB with Shimano M355 brakes.  The rear brake lever got messed up somehow.  The snapring that holds the plunger/piston into the master cylinder assembly got popped out and is missing.

I was hoping someone knows the part number for this snap ring so I could buy that rather than a whole new brake lever assembly.

Does anyone have a parts manual or parts sheet/drawing of this brake lever assembly?

The part number on the brake lever assembly is Shimano P/N BL-M355.

Comment: If you search for a Shimano part number + ev, you normally get the result: https://www.paul-lange.de/index.php/de/explosionszeichnungen.html?file=files/paullange/07_Service/04_Downloads/Shimano/explosionszeichnungen/BL/BL-M355-3812.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The circlip and master cylinder are not shown in the Expanded View or Dealer Manual. I looked up EV-BL-M975 for a lever I own which I know uses a circlip and that document doesn't show it either.

I don't think Shimano intend for the levers' hydraulic internals to be serviceable, whereas many of the reservoir covers and seals, lever blades, pivots and other parts are listed with part numbers.

A machine shop may be able to identify a compatible circlip by examining the other lever. As Shimano's hydraulic brakes seem to be compatible throughout the range, I expect the cylinder diameter will be identical and the same circlip will be used.

If the circlip was pulled out, it's likely the groove will be damaged. Personally, I would buy a used Shimano hydraulic brake lever (any model should work but it's best to get one which uses the same fitting size) and fit that.